# imu_filter_madgwick not publishing on imu/data

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running the sample bag-file "ardrone_imu.bag", I am remapping the topic "/ardrone/imu" to "/imu/data_raw" since according to http://wiki.ros.org/imu_filter_madgwick, that is the nodes subscribed topic. I run the filter with:

```
rosrun imu_filter_madgwick imu_filter_node _use_magnetic_field_msg:=false _publish_debug_topics:=true
```

Looking at `rostopic list -v` and `rostopic info` on the topics I see that the `/Imufilter` is subscribing on `/imu/data_raw` and the `/imu/data_raw` topic seems fine when echoing it. But when I echo `/imu/data` where the fused orientation is supposed to be, nothing appears. I can't see any debug topics publishing either. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$ rostopic list -v

Published topics:
 * /imu/rpy/raw [geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped] 1 publisher
 * /ardrone/mag [geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped] 1 publisher
 * /imu/data [sensor_msgs/Imu] 1 publisher
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 2 publishers
 * /tf [tf2_msgs/TFMessage] 1 publisher
 * /ImuFilter/parameter_descriptions [dynamic_reconfigure/ConfigDescription] 1 publisher
 * /clock [rosgraph_msgs/Clock] 1 publisher
 * /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher
 * /ImuFilter/parameter_updates [dynamic_reconfigure/Config] 1 publisher
 * /imu/magnetic_field [sensor_msgs/MagneticField] 1 publisher
 * /imu/rpy/filtered [geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped] 1 publisher
 * /imu/data_raw [sensor_msgs/Imu] 1 publisher

Subscribed topics:
 * /imu/magnetic_field [sensor_msgs/MagneticField] 1 subscriber
 * /imu/mag [geometry_msgs/Vector3Stamped] 1 subscriber
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber
 * /imu/data_raw [sensor_msgs/Imu] 1 subscriber
```

and

```
$ rostopic echo /imu/data_raw
  header: 
      seq: 3691
      stamp: 
        secs: 1352907263
        nsecs: 373922350
      frame_id: ardrone_base_link
    orientation: 
      x: 0.149071718242
      y: 0.115987049271
      z: -0.981395641479
      w: 0.0344560895747
    orientation_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    angular_velocity: 
      x: -0.265703596544
      y: 0.275929386036
      z: 0.0895630139048
    angular_velocity_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    linear_acceleration: 
      x: 0.448720367998
      y: 0.806759922206
      z: 8.29265825748
    linear_acceleration_covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

and

```
$ rostopic info /imu/data_raw
Type: sensor_msgs/Imu

Publishers: 
 * /player (http://user:44850/)

Subscribers: 
 * /ImuFilter (http://user:38581/)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236966/imu_filter_madgwick-not-publishing-on-imu/data/) by [hashten](https://answers.ros.org/users/27158/hashten/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry for the late reply. You forgot to remap the magnetometer topic. When `use_mag` is set to true (default), the node waits for matching pairs of messages on topics `/imu/data_raw` and either `/imu/mag` or `/imu/magnetic_field`. If the user does not provide one of the magnetic field topics, no data will be published on `/imu/data`. There should be a warning in this case; I've opened a [ticket](https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/imu_tools/issues/61) for that.

You probably started everything like this:

```
roscore
rosparam set use_sim_time true
rosrun imu_filter_madgwick imu_filter_node _use_magnetic_field_msg:=false _publish_debug_topics:=true
rosbag play --clock $(rospack find imu_filter_madgwick)/sample/ardrone_imu.bag /ardrone/imu:=/imu/data_raw
```

**Option 1:**

rosbag play ... /ardrone/imu:=/imu/data_raw **/ardrone/mag:=/imu/mag**

**Option 2:** (if you don't have or don't want to use magnetometer data)

rosrun imu_filter_madgwick imu_filter_node ...  **_use_mag:=false**

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aaron cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/27622/aaron-cheng/) on 2016-07-28**:
Hi Martin, I just set use_mag to false and it works like a charm. Many thanks.

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-07-28**:
What additional benefits does the magnetic field message provide?